# What are some examples of code that rely on 'typeof null' returning an object?

Tags: javascript, typeof

I am reading this book called YDKJS and it's mentioned that:

> `typeof null` is an interesting case, because it errantly returns `"object"`, when you'd expect it to return `"null"`.
>
> Warning: This is a long-standing bug in JS, but one that is likely never going to be fixed. Too much code on the Web relies on the bug and thus fixing it would cause a lot more bugs!

I can't wrap my head around any code that makes use of the return type of a `null`. Can anyone please give some example use cases?

Comment: There probably aren't any *good* use cases, but given the number of script-writers in the world, doubtlessly at least a few have written silly code that's made it into production that relies on such a thing.

Comment: Here it is referenced as the return type of the `typeof` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that they make use of return type of a `null`, but the return type of a **variable**.

What I mean is that there are so many cases where devs are writting:

```
if (typeof something === "object"){

}
```

And **expect** whatever passes this condition to be, among others, `null` as well.

So they rely on the fact that whatever relies in that block of `true` statement to hold even a `null` value.

Let's say we have this piece of code:

```
switch (typeof something) {
  case "object":
    if (something) {
      doSomethingWithObject(something);
    } else {
      rejectTransaction(); // we have null
    }
    break;
  case "undefined":
    throwAMeaningfulError();
    break;
  default:
    doSomethingWithNumberOrString(something);
    break;
}
```

As can be seen, we're handling all cases, be it `object`, `undefined`, `string`, `number` or `null`.

If this bug would be fixed, and `typeof null` would return `null`, the `rejectTransaction` would never be called. Instead, the `doSomethingWithNumberOrString` would be called.

I'm not saying this is a good example of code, but something that might be out there that might break because devs relied on the fact that `typeof null` returned `"object"` and not `"null"`

Comment: *devs relied on the fact that `typeof null` returned `"object"`*: that's a convention that makes sense. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a type point of view, `null` being of type `object` makes sense. Like it makes sense that `NaN` and `Infinity` are of type `number`.

**Because what else would a nullable variable refer to, if not to an object?**

Primitives are immutable in javascript. You won't get a reference of them but a copy.